# How to use FlexibleOptionGroup inside vaadin table?

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, vaadin7

I need to use `OptionGroup` inside my table cell of one column. If one item is selected other item should be deselected. In general `optiongroup` we cannot add item to different cells of table. So I am using `FlexibleOptionGroup`. But I don't know how to use this using table field factory like this. If `propertyId.equals("option")` the `optiongroup Item` should add to the table cell.

```
      resultTable.setImmediate(true);
      resultTable.setTableFieldFactory(new DefaultFieldFactory() {
            public Field<?> createField(Container container, final Object itemId,
                                  Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
                              if (propertyId.equals("option")) {

                              }
            Field field = super.createField(container, itemId, propertyId,
                    uiContext);
            field.setReadOnly(true);
            return field;
        }

    });
```

Comment: what do you mean by "other item should be deselected"?  another already selected row in the table?  could you explain your usecase a little better or even provide an example, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: In my table now am selecting particular row by clicking on that row. But I want to select a row using radio button where radio buttons are one of the column of my table. If I select first row then if I select second, first row should get deselected.